# How can I swap numbers in a two-dimensional array in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

These are sector numbers that may only occur once
per row and once per column. As can be seen, the number 3 appears twice for row two below:

```
1   2
3   3
4   1
2   4
```

I was able to solve this with the following code

```
For a As Integer = 0 To AR.GetLength(0) - 1
    If AR(a, 3) > 0 Then
        If AR(a, 1) = AR(a, 3) Then
            Dim Swap_Sector = AR(a, 3)
            Dim Swap_Number = AR(a, 4)
            If a < AR.GetLength(0) - 1 Then
                AR(a, 3) = AR(a + 1, 3)
                AR(a, 4) = AR(a + 1, 4)
                AR(a + 1, 3) = Swap_Sector
                AR(a + 1, 4) = Swap_Number
            Else
                AR(a, 3) = AR(a - 1, 3)
                AR(a, 4) = AR(a - 1, 4)
                AR(a - 1, 3) = Swap_Sector
                AR(a - 1, 4) = Swap_Number
                       
            End If
        End If
    End If
 Next a
```

resulting in

```
1    3
3    2
4    1
2    4
```

Now my question. How can I solve this if I have three columns?
For example:

```
1     3     4
3     2     3
4     1     2
2     4     1
```

Here the number 3 appears twice in row two. How can I replace this after checking with number 1 from row four and number 3 to row four?

Comment: Whatever this is about is not clear to me.  What if 4 appeared in row 3 col 2 in the first example?

Comment: The same number should not appear on any row
the same goes for the columns
in fact like a 4x4 sudoku

Comment: This comment should be in your question. You may want to look into how to construct a Sudoku board and apply it to 4x4

Comment: It seems if you can change the initial data, any correct answer is acceptable because it can be considered as the edited data. In this approach, first a set of all possible order of numbers for a column is created. Suppose you have `m` rows and `n` columns. This set (named `A` for example) will have `P(m,m)=m!` items, where each item is an array or a list of integers with `m` non-repetative elements from 1 to m.  Now we create another set from `A` , (`B`) which is all possible combination of selectin `n` items from `A`.
`B` will have `C(m!,n)` items, where each item is a potential answer.

Comment: Continued: Next step is to eliminate non-acceptable items from `B`. Since column-condition is already achieved when making `A`, only row-condition checking is adequate. Finally, any item in `B` is an acceptable answer.